# Still getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas' ' despite having installed Pandas, anaconda,

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am a beginner in python. . Trying to pull data from Strava, but first trying to set up pandas.

Using a mac, on the Terminal, and Atom to create the programs.

I'm Running Python version 3.7.3

I've just downloaded and installed Anaconda as well.

I thought I had downloaded and installed Pandas and Numpy:

```
Successfully installed numpy-1.18.1 pandas-1.0.1 python-dateutil-2.8.1 pytz-2019.3 six-1.14.0
```

But everytime I run this code i write in Atom:

```
import Pandas as pd import numpy as np col_names = ['id','type']
activities = pd.DataFrame(columns=col_names)
access_token = "access_token=XXXXXXx" # replace with your access token here
url = "https://www.strava.com/api/v3/activities"
```

This is what I get back in Terminal:

```
`File "pskw.py", line 2, in <module> 
import Pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Pandas'`
```

Any idea where I am going wrong?

I've read through many articles on Stackoverflow but my problem persists.

Any advice?

Comment: Have you tried with lowercase 'pandas'?

Comment: try with lower case pandas not Camelcase

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change the `import Pandas` to

```
import pandas as pd
```